# Сервер отвечает каракулями при GET запросе

Tags: node.js, http

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер отвечает каракулями, можно подсказку?

Comment: Подсказка: кодировка

Comment: Проблема с кодировкой. Попробуйте к ***Content-Type*** добавить ещё ***charset=UTF-8***. Возможно даже такой вариант ***"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"***

Comment: @EgorTrutnev добавить "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" в ответ сервера или в запрос клиента?

Comment: @nörbörnën в ответ. Проблема именно в ответе пользователю. Он приходит, но не в той кодировке. Нужна именно **UTF-8**